# How to Implement Azure Ad Login Mechanism using msal4j with Spring boot application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, http-status-code-404, msal4j

I would like to connect to Azure AD using client certificate - not secret.

I have to implement using msal4j.

I tried msal4j with Spring mvc but facing [errorpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnFc0.png) error while I am redirecting to specific API.
I used server.servlet.context-path=/sample
[Controller Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u83Ig.png)